# How set ZFS ACL permissions on CentOS 6

Tags: linux, centos, solaris, zfs, access-control-list

I use last ZFS ([ZFS for Linux](http://zfsonlinux.org/)) on the CentOS 6.
Create successfully pool, all working fine. But i have one question.

How i can set ACL for ZFS folder/file?
GNU ls, chmod, and other coreutils not support(?) it.

On the Solaris/OpenSolaris/OpenIndiana/Nexenta i use

> /usr/bin/chmod \
>   A=owner@:rwxpdDaARWcCos:fd-----:allow,group@:rwxpdDaARWcCos:fd-----:allow,everyone@:rwxpdDaARWcCos:fd-----:deny
>   /ZFS/FOLDER/

What i must use for CentOS linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this for now. This is stated in the [admin guide](http://pthree.org/2013/01/02/zfs-administration-part-xvi-getting-and-setting-properties/):

> Currently, ACLs are not functioning in ZFS on Linux as of 0.6.0-rc13.

Answer (score 7):

As of ZFS on Linux version 0.6.3, ACLs are now supported.

To enable them, you must set the `acltype` dataset property to the value `posixacl`, e.g.:

```
zfs set acltype=posixacl tank/home
```

If you haven't already, you should also set `xattr` to `sa`:

```
zfs set xattr=sa tank
```

POSIX ACLs are stored as extended attributes.  Unfortunately, the standard way of storing extended attributes can cause serious performance hits on Linux, so you really need the "system attribute" storage method.

Comment: The [ZFS man pages](https://zfsonlinux.org/manpages/0.8.2/man8/zfs.8.html) provide details about these options.  For example these options have the following possible settings: `acltype = off | noacl | posixacl` and `xattr = on | off | sa`.